# Mojo::DOM - How to return more than one attribute

Tags: perl, mojolicious, mojo-dom

I'm new to Mojolicious, to find the title for a link within a p tag with class Module e.g.

```
<p class="Module"><a class="story" href="http://intranet/blah" >Link Text is here</a></p>
```

I use the following code:

```
my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new( $page );

for my $elm ( $dom->find('p.Module > a.story')->each ){
    print $elm->text ."\n";
}
```

Pretty crude but it's functional. What I can't figure out as yet (it could be too late at night for me) is how to return the href and the link text. Please put me out of my misery.

Comment: *“Pretty crude but it's functional”* It seems fine to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need the [`attr`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM#attr) method:

```
my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new( $page );

for my $elm ( $dom->find('p.Module > a.story')->each ){
    print $elm->text, ' ', $elm->attr('href'), "\n";
}
```

For a quick tutorial on [`Mojo::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::UserAgent) and [`Mojo::DOM`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM), check out [Mojocast episode 5](http://mojocasts.com/e5)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a mojo-y way of doing it by using [Mojo::Collection](http://www.metacpan.org/module/Mojo::Collection)'s `map`:

```
use v5.10;

use Mojo::DOM;
use Data::Dumper;

my $page =<<'HTML';
<p class="Module"><a class="story" href="http://intranet/blah" >Link Text is here</a></p>
HTML

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new( $page );

my @links = $dom
    ->find('p.Module > a.story')
    ->map( sub { [ $_->text, $_->attr( 'href' ) ] } );

say Dumper \@links;
```